# Searching does not work on the iPhone (4s)

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, iphone, safari

How can I [**search**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#searching) for Q&A in [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) on the iPhone? It does not work as it does in my browser on the PC (Windows/IT).

There is a **textbox** visible when I open up the menu bar (1st line of the screen), but when I enter search texts it **doesn't filter by the keywords**.

The **iPhone** generally shows the pages in **Safari** nicely and I can answer questions, only search does not work.

**On the PC**, the search is triggered automatically - which is not the case on the iPhone. Maybe a "Search" button on the website could be added to trigger the search manually (but this would be a task for the website developers) ?

Does anyone know a solution (without the need to change the website) ?

---

**Update:** I've tried to use http://www.stackoverflow.com/search instead (as a workaround), which I've saved as  a bookmark. But this is not quite the same functionality, as it seems to be rather a meta-search than a site-internal search (because the textbox in the top-line does also not work here).

Comment: The search is not triggered automatically, it reacts to hitting Return. As far as I know, this can be achieved by double-tapping.

Comment: Double-tapping doesn't work. I've started a bounty, hopefully there'll be a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for searching on the iPhone:

1. Click on the **triangle icon** to drop down the **stackoverflow menu bar**:
   [image: menu bar]
2. Enter the search text in the **text box** below the menu bar:

   [image: search textbox]
3. Click on the **GO** button of the **Safari browser** (note that this button might have a different label depending on the language you've set up for your iPhone):

   [image: safari go button]

This will reload the page filtered by the keywords you have typed before.